# How to add each stock daily price in a banner (marquee) in navbarpage rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, marquee

Good mornning.
I am working with financial data (daily prices of some stocks)
I would like to insert in a banner/marquee efficient way the information about the current prices of the shares of the listed companies as shown in the following picture.
Refer to the image [image] and the [link](https://www.impaxis-securities.com/)

Below is my code
Thanks in advance

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(bslib)

##The information i want to display in the banner
qt <- list(Symbole = c("ABJC", "BICC", "BNBC", "BOAB", "BOABF", "BOAC", "BOAM", "BOAN", 
                       "BOAS", "CABC", "CBIBF", "CFAC", "CIEC", "ECOC", "ETIT", "FTSC", 
                       "NEIC", "NSBC", "NTLC", "ONTBF", "ORGT", "PALC", "PRSC", "SAFC", 
                       "SCRC", "SDCC", "SDSC", "SEMC", "SGBC", "SHEC", "SIBC", "SICC", 
                       "SIVC", "SLBC", "SMBC", "SNTS", "SOGC", "SPHC", "STAC", "STBC", 
                       "SVOC", "TTLC", "TTLS", "TTRC", "UNLC", "UNXC"),
           `Cours cloture (FCFA)` = c(1600, 5855, 2200, 5650, 6140, 5310, 1380, 5145, 2500, 1190, 
                                      9750, 1160, 2150, 4675, 23, 1700, 740, 5755, 5275, 4195, 3905, 
                                      7505, 4715, 850, 920, 4450, 2500, 735, 11200, 980, 3985, 4865, 
                                      775, 165000, 7080, 14150, 5000, 5100, 1440, 5850, 0, 2245, 2050, 
                                      0, 0, 2055),
           `Variation(%)` = c("1,54", "-6,91", "0", "0", "0,16", "-0,94", "-1,09", "-0,78", 
                              "-2,72", "0", "0,3", "0", "-2,33", "0", "0", "2,41", "7,25", 
                              "0", "0", "0", "-0,64", "1,96", "-7,29", "6,51", "2,17", "0", 
                              "-0,97", "0", "0", "0", "-1,27", "0,31", "-7,1", "0,61", "0,07", 
                              "0,71", "1,41", "-0,38", "7,29", "-0,08", "0", "0,67", "0", "0", 
                              "0", "0,48")
)  

qt <- as_tibble(qt)

#A vector contening element of each stock
aaa1 <- NULL
for (i in 1 : nrow(qt)){
  aaa1 <- append(aaa1, paste0(qt[i, ], collapse = " "))
}

##aaa1 is the information i really want to display in my banner
#head(aaa1)
# [1] "ABJC 1600 1,54"  "BICC 5855 -6,91" "BNBC 2200 0"     "BOAB 5650 0"    
# [5] "BOABF 6140 0,16" "BOAC 5310 -0,94"


shinyOptions(bslib = TRUE)
bs_global_theme()
bs_theme_base_colors(bg = "#002B36", fg = "#EEE8D5")
bs_theme_accent_colors(primary = "#2AA198")
thematic::thematic_shiny()
theme=shinytheme("cerulean")# returns URL of a shiny theme
themeSelector() ## not required but can be used to select the theme

#My shiny app is similar to this one
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme=shinytheme("cerulean"),# returns URL of a shiny theme
  themeSelector(), ## not required but can be used to select the theme
  navbarPage(
    title= "BRVM stock exchange", position = "static-top", id="nav",
    tabPanel("Introduction", value = "Introduction", icon = icon("info-circle")),
             
  # Application title
  tabPanel("Stocks market Shiny!",
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar with a slider input
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs",
                  "Number of observations:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 1000,
                  value = 500)
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(  
      tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("About society",icon = icon("address-card", class="fa-regular fa-address-card"),
               plotOutput("distPlot"),
               ),
      tabPanel("Data summary",icon = icon("table"),
               verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
      tabPanel("Forcast", "Forcast", icon = icon("list-alt"),
               plotOutput("dplot"))
      )
      
    ) #main
  )
)))

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  cs <- new.env()
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs))
  })
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
  ok <- summary(rnorm(500))
  ok
})
  output$dplot <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(input$obs))
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```